# command-line / batch file to list all the jar files?

Tags: windows, dir

I want to list all the jar files in subdirectories of a specified path, on a Windows computer, along with the file size & times.

`dir /s` gives me too much information. `dir /s *.jar` sort of does what I want, but gives me a bunch of information per-directory that I don't care about. `dir /b/s *.jar` is brief but doesn't give me the time or filesize.

Is there a command that will just list the jar files + filesize/time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could do this:

```
for /r %i in (*.jar) do echo  %~ti %~zi %i
```

which will iterate over all dirs (including the current one) and echos out the `*.jar` names. It will also echo out the `echo` command, so you may want to pipe the output to a file:

```
for /r %i in (*.jar) do echo %~ti %~zi %i >> myJars.txt
```

or put it in a bat:

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (*.jar) do echo %%~ti %%~zi %%i
```

note the double `%`'s in the `.bat` version.

Comment: To suppress the output of the 'echo' command, precede the command with '@'.

    for /r %i in (*.jar) do @echo %~ti %~zi %i

Answer (score 1):

This command line works:

```
dir /s *.jar | find "jar"
```

It pipes the output of "dir" into the "find" command to filter it - filtering out lines not containing "jar" like the lines with "Directory".

However it is only 99.9% bullet proof. If a folder contains 
"jar" in its name AND this folder contains a jar file then 
you need to filter that out:

```
dir /s *.jar | find "jar" | find /V "Directory of"
```

"/V" means that all lines NOT containing "Directory of" will 
be printed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I was able to get to what you needed was

```
dir /p /s *.jar
```

This gives out the files' directory locations, their size, and their date/timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding paths:

```
for /r c:\your\path %i in (*.jar) do @echo %~nxi %~zi %~ti
```

Including paths:

```
for /r c:\your\path %i in (*.jar) do @echo %~i %~zi %~ti
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no particular reason for using the command line (like a batch script need)
You could just use the **Explorer**, **Search** to list `*.jar` files from the base folder.
You will get the *size* and *date* information and the list can be sorted in a few ways.

This will be a GUI solution.
I always wondered why Windows does not allow me to **export such a search result to CSV/XLS/TXT**.
All that hard work of sifting through the folders goes waste; cannot post-process the output.
Anyone has ideas on such an export to file?